# Validate email - Javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I know this question has been asked numerous times because I've been searching this site for a solution for the past day and a half. I think my javascript is messed up because i've tested by php code and it works fine. Am i just making some stupid error?

I want to be able to edit the existing HTML page using javascript. NOT with PHP

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <body>  
            <script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
            <script src = "validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

            <form id = "emailCheck" action = "index.html" onsubmit = "return check();">
                <input type="text" id="email" /><br /> 
                <button id="submit">Check</button> 
                </div> 
                <div id="response"></div>
            </form>

        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

validate.js - This makes the call to check.php and alters index.html accordingly. I'm trying to get this script to run after the submit button is pressed.

```
function check() {

    var emailValue = document.getElementById('email').value;
    $.post('check.php',{email:emailValue},function(retVal){
        //Alert user avaliability of email
          if(retVal == "true") {
            document.getElementById('response').innerHTML="Unavaliable";
            return false;

          }
          else {
            document.getElementById('response').innerHTML="Avaliable";
            return true;
          }
    });

}
```

check.php - This accesses the database and echos if the email is contained within the database

```
<?php

    $email= $_POST['email'];

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "accounts") or die(mysqli_error());

    $sql = "    SELECT Email, Password
            FROM users
            WHERE Email = '$email';";

    $success = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($success);

    if($numrows != 0)
    {
     // email is Unavaliable
     echo "true";
    }
    else{
     // email is Avaliable
     echo "false";
    }
?>
```

Comment: First, use `<input type="email"/>` and not `<input type="text"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `event.preventDefault();` to your js.

```
function check() {
    event.preventDefault();

    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in php

```
<?php

// set error reporting level
if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.3.0', '>=') == 1)
  error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);
else
  error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $sLogin = escape($_POST['login']);
    $sPass = escape($_POST['pass']);
    $sCPass = escape($_POST['cpass']);
    $sEmail = escape($_POST['email']);
    $iGender = (int)$_POST['gender'];

    $sErrors = '';
    if (strlen($sLogin) >= 1 and strlen($sLogin) <= 25) {
        if (strlen($sPass) >= 1 and strlen($sPass) <= 25) {
            if (strlen($sEmail) >= 1 and strlen($sEmail) <= 55) {
                if ($sPass == $sCPass) {
                    if (ereg('^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+$', $sEmail)) {
                        if ($iGender == '1' xor $iGender == '0') {
                            $sVcode = escape($_POST['vcode']);
                            if (! isset($_SESSION['valdiation_code'])) {
                                // Here you can send him some verification code (by email or any another ways)
                                $sCode = uniqid(rand(), true);
                                $_SESSION['valdiation_code'] = md5($sCode);

                            } elseif (md5($sVcode) == $_SESSION['valdiation_code']) {
                                // Here you can add him to database
                                // mysql_query('INSERT INTO ....

                                // display step 3 (final step)
                                echo strtr(file_get_contents('templates/step3.html'), array());
                                exit;
                            } else {
                                $sErrors = 'Verification code is wrong';
                            }
                        } else {
                            $sErrors = 'Gender is wrong';
                        }
                    } else {
                        $sErrors = 'Email is wrong';
                    }
                } else {
                    $sErrors = 'Passwords are not the same';
                }
            } else {
                $sErrors = 'Address email is too long';
            }
        } else {
            $sErrors = 'Password is too long';
        }
    } else {
        $sErrors = 'Login is too long';
    }

    // display step 2
    $aParams = array(
        '{errors}' => $sErrors,
        '{login}' => $sLogin,
        '{pass}' => $sPass,
        '{cpass}' => $sCPass,
        '{gender}' => $iGender,
        '{email}' => $sEmail,
        '{vcode}' => $sCode
    );
    echo strtr(file_get_contents('templates/step2.html'), $aParams);
    exit;
}

// unset validation code if exists
unset($_SESSION['valdiation_code']);

// draw registration page
echo strtr(file_get_contents('templates/main_page.html'), array());

// extra useful function to make POST variables more safe
function escape($s) {
    //return mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($s)); // uncomment in when you will use connection with database
    return strip_tags($s);
}
```

mail validation using JavaScript

```
<script language="javascript">

function checkEmail() {

    var email = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

    if (!filter.test(email.value)) {
    alert('Please provide a valid email address');
    email.focus;
    return false;
 }
}</script>
```